# what is label shift?

Tags: machine-learning, named-entity-recognition

I'm studying a paper about Named Entity Recognition. The following is a part of the abstract:

> To assess the robustness of NER systems, we propose an evaluation method that focuses on subsets of tokens that represent specific
> sources of errors: unknown words and label shift or ambiguity.

I don't know what "label shift" definition is. The paper doesn't explain it and I can not find anything that I could understand by Googling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Label shift is the opposite of a covariate shift.**

 In this case, the assumption is that even though the feature distribution remains the same, *the Label distribution might changes.*

 *e.g. Symptoms --> Diseases*

 It can be different for different country *(based on medical education of the Country/Doctor)*

 It can change with time also based on advancement in Medical knowledge

 
 Similar logic can be built for *"Words --> Slang".* It can change with time due to the acceptance of these words.

*Read the references for a formal explanation.*

References-

*[Dive into Deep Learning](https://d2l.ai/chapter_multilayer-perceptrons/environment.html)

[Detecting and Correcting for Label Shift with Black Box Predictors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03916.pdf)*

Comment: Do these shifts affect so called class-distribution independent metrics such as TPR or FPR?